# Use .smallCaps() in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, typography, xcode11.3, smallcaps

Im trying to change my text to small caps in SwiftUI.
But I don't understand how to apply the Method to my text.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/3084273-smallcaps

I've tried different ways, here are two of them:

```
Text("Typography")
    .font(.system(size: 24))
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .smallCaps()
```

-

```
 Text("Typography")
     .font(.system(.body, textStyle: .smallCaps))
```

How can I set my letters to small caps?
I’m using Xcode 11.3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That code finally worked for me:

```
Text("Typography")
    .font(Font.system(.body).smallCaps())
```

Comment: Slightly shorter way to write it, if you're interested: `Text("Typography")
    .font(.body.smallCaps())`